# Which Professor do you send you pokemon to in Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

If Willow is the traveling, exploring profosser in the game does he really have room in his camper for all those transfered pokemon? So if not... are we sending them to Oak?

Answer (score 5):

In-game, all transferred Pokemon are sent to Willow. The act of transferring Pokemon is the equivalent of releasing them, so there is no storage required.

> As you catch more Pokémon, you may transfer some of them to Professor Willow to free up your Pokémon storage. You’ll receive Candy in exchange for transferring a Pokémon. Be careful - you can’t get your Pokémon back after you’ve transferred it away.

[Source](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/235887047-Transferring-Pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: It actually does not say Willow. But thanks.

Comment: What does not actually say Willow?

Answer (score 2):

[From Bulbapedia:](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Professor_Willow)

> The player can transfer Pokémon to Professor Willow using the
>   "Transfer" option on the status screen in exchange for 1 Candy for
>   that Pokémon's evolutionary family

Professor Oak is only referenced in Pokemon Go outside the game, from Niantic marketing videos (those for Meltan), and on Twitter posts. Seeing how Willow is the only professor mentioned in-game, it would stand to reason that he is the professor the game is referring to.

Also this is a game where Pokemon are stored in small balls and you can carry up to 1500 of those balls at any time. And said balls can somehow be transferred to someone in his camper. I'm certain Willow has found a way to store all those Pokemon.